# Is it possible to create a module that creates a specific Dom element in js?

Tags: javascript

I've got a question. Is it possible to create a module in Javascript, that instantiates a Dom element? For example I've got the class `Canvas`.

```
class Canvas {

    constructor(width, height, context){
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.context = context;
        this.setupCanvas();
    }

    setupCanvas(){
        console.log(this.width, this.height, this.context);
        let canvas = document.createElement('canvas');

        canvas.width = this.width;
        canvas.height = this.height;

        let context = canvas.getContext(this.context);
        context.fillStyle = 'red';

        return canvas;
    }
}

export default Canvas;
```

I'm sry for the bad formatting, but I don't know how to get it better. 
This module exports the entire class and after that, I want to use it in a file let's call it `index.js`. There I import the module with the call `import Canvas from './Canvas/canvas`. So the rest of the code looks like

```
import Canvas from './Canvas/canvas';

let canvas = new Canvas(80, 80, '2d');
canvas.setupCanvas;
document.body.appendChild(canvas);
```

Right now it wouldn't work, because I get the error: TypeError: Argument 1 ('node') to Node.appendChild must be an instance of Node

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code has 2 problems. First your `Canvas` class is not a canvas node but has the function `setupCanvas` to *create* a canvas. Next you aim to call `setupCanvas` twice: once from the constructor and later with `canvas.setupCanvas;`. However notice that `canvas.setupCanvas;` does *nothing* because you're missing the `()`.

What you could do is to first remove `this.setupCanvas()` from your constructor and then use the result of `setupCanvas` when you call it later:

```
import Canvas from './Canvas/canvas';

let canvas = new Canvas(80, 80, '2d');
document.body.appendChild(canvas.setupCanvas());
```

Comment: Now it works! Thank you very much! What do I have to do, that the function setupCanvas is automatically called, when an Canvas object is created? So my target is to just need to instantiate canvas and than call the appendChild() function of the Dom. For example: 
`let canvas = new Canvas(80, 80, '2d');
document.body.appendChild(canvas);`
And the Canvas class would look like:
'class Canvas {
constructor(width, height, context){
this.width = width;
this.height = height;
this.context = context;
this.setupCanvas() //to automatically call the setup process which return the canvas object`

Comment: you cant. because then `canvas` would be your canvas class and not a DOM node. However you could just use a function instead of a class and use the return value.

Comment: Okay thank you very much! That's a very nice explanation. What would you think would be the best way to create a website just using vanilla javascript without any frameworks at all?

Comment: Honestly? Don't do it. Frameworks and libraries are *not* evil! But thats 100% my personal opinion.